# Edits in .asp net website wont show

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

i've got an issue with website made in asp.net. A site is published and online, i've made some modifications, republished site on my computer and just uploaded a .aspx file into the server via ftp.

First time it seems to have worked after a while. But i've made a small error and want to edit it again, i did the same, but it wont change. Could it be that i need to wait some time before changes are seen? Or could it be that there needs to be a server restart or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've edited something in the aspx.cs page you will need to upload the `bin` directory to the remote site, or better still republish the whole site.

If it is a change to the .aspx, css or javasctipt file, the original will most likely be cached in your browser. Try a differrent browser brand or refreshing the page, ctrl-f5 does a complete refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If this error was by any chance a CSS mistake, that can be easily fixed by adding a "?" at the end of the address since CSS files are normally stored in the cache of the browser and the ? tells the browser to update them. Same thing is true about JavaScripts which are kept in individual files

I'd recommend you to use the Visual Studio `Publish Website` under the `Build` instead of manually uploading the site over FTP. That built in publisher provides you many advantages of which one of them is the same issue you have faced. When you make a small change, fixing the error in host would be very faster by republishing the site that way rather than manually upping it over FTP.